# List the all apps in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list all apps in android device with queryIntentActivities method but the list doesn't return all the apps , It returns only three of them. Here is my code:

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> allApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : allApps) {
        Log.d("Labels", String.valueOf(ri.loadLabel(packageManager)));
    }
```

is there anyone now why it returns only 3 applications ?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-get-users-installed-apps-in-android-11-b4a4d2754286

Comment: does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely trying to do this on Android 11. Make sure you add the `<uses-permission android:name"android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">` permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

> While I haven't tested this aspect of R DP2 yet, it appears that your
> app now can't find out what other apps are installed, on a general
> basis. The cited example is queryIntentActivities(), but to make this
> really work you would need to seriously lobotomize PackageManager. You
> can whitelist certain packages and certain  structures
> to try to get by this for certain use cases. And, this is where the
> mysterious QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission seen in DP1 comes into play —
> this permission removes these new restrictions. Given the "look for
> Google Play to provide guidelines for apps that need this permission"
> caveat, it is safest to assume that if you try using it, eventually
> you will be banned from the Play Store by a bot.

Comment: this is working as i want but the problem is when i add this line it returns the red line. But as i said it works? Do you have an idea why it returns red line?

Comment: what is "red-line" message.

Comment: the solution wants me to add this line in the permission blocks "tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" and i think this is solution works anyway its all good :)

Comment: Please read. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60766583/5595926

Comment: The project that i work on is a test project so I'm not gonna release it so main purpose is to get the application list at the beginning . But you helped me a lot thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer is correct, it will help others if you confirm it.