# How to get recent active apps in android?

Tags: java, android

How we find recently running application. I use this code but show only working app.

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " 
            + recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()
            + "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Comment: Did you read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284205/how-to-get-list-of-recent-apps-with-android-api-21-lollipop

Comment: Yes it also show only working app

Comment: May be your can try `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES ` permission? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679685/what-does-query-all-packages-permission-do

Comment: @rosuh thank you, worked with QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES  permission

Answer (score 0):

I found something in here which should help:

https://gist.github.com/rmkrishna/7e133bcf1a918a02f2c882c1d7011b18

First of all, it gets all recent apps.

It has the `Android Manifest` and `Java` code.

I think it's fine to give you this since the contributor has been gone for several months now.

I thought of giving you this link since I read in your comment that yours only shows working apps, if that above doesn't want to work...

Tell me, I'll offer an alternative.