# Not able to open other app packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In our flutter TV application, we are trying the open few entertainment apps using [DeviceApps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) . The following methods doesn't open the App though it is installed on the device.

```
 DeviceApps.openApp("com.sonyliv");
```

Not able to figure out why sonyliv is not opening.

Note: Please ignore  Touch is not implemented to this app currently.So only tap works.

Complete snippet

```
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class ListAppsPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const ListAppsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListAppsBody(),
    );
  }
}

class ListAppsBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListAppBodyState createState() => _ListAppBodyState();
}

class _ListAppBodyState extends State {
  List listApps = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getApp();
  }

   void _getApp() async{
    List _apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(includeAppIcons: true);
    for(var app in _apps){

     // print(app.apkFilePath);

    if(!app.packageName.contains("example")) {
        var item = AppModel(
        title: app.appName,
        package: app.packageName,
        icon: app.icon,
      );
      listApps.add(item);
    }

    }

    //reloading state
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listApps.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int i) => Column(
        children: [
           ListTile(
            leading: Image.memory(listApps[i].icon),
            title:  Text(listApps[i].title),
            subtitle:  Text(listApps[i].package),
            onTap: (){
              DeviceApps.openApp(listApps[i].package);
      
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppModel{
  final String title;
  final String package;
  final Uint8List icon;

  AppModel({
   required this.title,
   required this.package,
   required this.icon
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it python 2.7?

Comment: @George This is Dart if you're asking about the programming language

Comment: Your code worked in my phone.

Comment: @agcgn Yes, It opens other apps on device & tv as intended but not sonyliv

Comment: @anandyn02 I can open sonyliv app as well. Maybe try resetting your phone ?

Comment: Found solution myself

Comment: @anandyn02 Then, please answer your question so that other people can benefit.

Comment: read this question [What does QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679685/what-does-query-all-packages-permission-do)
this permission is important to open other app

Answer (score 0):

To open another app from within a Flutter app on the same device, you can use the **url_launcher** package. First, you need to add this package to your Flutter project's **pubspec.yaml** file. You can do this by adding the following line under **dependencies**:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0
```

Then, run the command **flutter pub get** to download the package.

Next, you can use the **url_launcher** package to open another app using its package identifier. In your case, the package identifier for the SonyLIV app is **com.sonyliv** . Use the following code as an example:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Open Another App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              openApp();
            },
            child: Text('Open SonyLIV App'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openApp() async {
    final String appUrl = 'com.sonyliv://';
    if (await canLaunch(appUrl)) {
      await launch(appUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $appUrl';
    }
  }
}
```

When you run the app, it will display a button labeled "Open SonyLIV App." When you click on the button, it will attempt to open the SonyLIV app on the same device if it is installed. If it's not installed, an exception will be thrown.

Please note that the app you're trying to open must be installed on the device for the code to work correctly.

Comment: the constructed uri under openApp is not launching the app. I found an alternative solution which opens the app. Instead of using 'com.sonyliv://' I'm calling https://www.sonyliv.com/dplnk?sony://details/